# increase /var partition by adding few disks

Tags: rhel, lvm, disk, vmware, xfs

Before one year I extend the `/var` on the redhat 7.x server as the following from `100G` to `200G`

```
notes:
a. VG-A is the VG
b. server is VM server
c. file-system is XFS
```

procedure:

```
1.  pvcreate /dev/sdb
2.  vgextend VG-A /dev/sdb
3.  lvresize --size +100G /dev/mapper/VG-A-lv_var
4.  xfs_growfs /var
```

so `/var` increased to `200G`

now we are thinking to add another `100G` to `/var` by adding a new disk – `sdc` , as we did in steps 1-4 , in order to increase `/var` to `300G`

so the meaning is that `sdb` and `sdc` will be allocated to `/var` , additional to part of `sda` disk ( `sda` disk is the OS disk )

**my question is**

is it ok to add ***2 disks*** in order to increase the `/var`?

I am asking because maybe adding number of disks , in order to extend `/var` size could be problematic for example if one of the disks ( `sdb/sdc` ) are failed . then `/var` will not functional

Comment: Are they really disks, or are they volumes from your VM host?

Comment: they are VMDK disks , from the VCENTER they are sdb and sdc

Comment: for example from the vcenter I add the disk sdc , and its show like a disk

Comment: You could expand the existing vmdk...

Comment: about - "expand the existing vmdk" its too risky its prod server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all — and this is hopefully a reminder — the answer to risk considerations when dealing with storage is to have a working backup and restore strategy.

With that in place, using virtual storage, the risk level is the same whether you extend the virtual disk or add a virtual disk. If you care about speedy recovery, you virtual storage should provide a snapshot feature which you could use.

To answer your main question, yes, adding another virtual disk is fine.

If you were using physical disks, then adding another disk would increase the risk of failure; again, the answer there is backups. For availability, again when using physical disks directly, you might want to consider some form of redundancy. In your case though, availability would be better addressed in your virtual storage layer.

Comment: another question please , is it possible to do snapshot for the disks - sdb and sdc ( in case disk failure then we can restore it )

Comment: Yes, I think it is, somewhere in vCenter...